# Setting variable to null confusion

Tags: php, variables, null

This works fine

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$a = null;
var_dump($a); // outputs no notice and NULL
```

yet this produces a notice?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$a;
var_dump($a); // outputs a notice followed by NULL
```

and this works

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
class some_class
{
    private $a;

    public static $b;

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo var_dump($this->a); // outputs NULL
    }
}
var_dump(some_class::$b); // outputs NULL
new some_class();
```

Comment: what is your question? `$a;` is not a valid assignment.

Comment: In the second example you didn't set `$a` to `null` but it is the default display when you attempt to access an undefined var.

Comment: @mistermartin I guess I would have expected the notice occur when declaring `$a;` rather than when trying to access it at `var_dump($a);`?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I made a few edits to an answer I posted earlier, outlining what's happening and not sure if you did see them (edits). I hope it shone some light on the subject ;-) (See comments in code also).

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the detailed answer. I guess my issue is that I understand the behavior but I just don't understand the why behind the standalone `$a;` not producing a notice. Please see my update. Does this mean that PHP initializes unassigned class properties to NULL upon compiling?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You're welcome, *cheers*. I'll have a closer look at it later, supper time ;-)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus And I'm back and had a look at your edit. TBH, I don't know much about classes as I never use them. I've had a look to see what I could add to my answer but can't think of anything (I would if I could). See if anyone else will pick up on it. *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I appreciate it. I wish I had posted my question with the class example right from the start. Maybe people would have taken a second look  before downvoting, oh well :)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus My pleasure. I can't see why it was downvoted, I thought it was a good question which I did upvote, if it's of any comfort.

Comment: I appreciate it. Maybe I'll try this question again in a few weeks. I think that the PHP tag gets so many cannon-fodder questions that auto-pilot kicks in for a lot of people, including myself :-P

Answer (score 2):

*Note to future readers.*

This answer was based on the original post, before introducing the use of a class https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36752382/1 and not marked as an additional edit.

---

> *"followed by NULL"*

- Which is *normal* behaviour.

From the manual on variables basics http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

> *"It is not necessary to initialize variables in PHP however it is a very good practice. Uninitialized variables have a default value of their type depending on the context in which they are used - booleans default to FALSE, integers and floats default to zero, strings (e.g. used in echo) are set as an empty string and arrays become to an empty array."*

Example #1 Default values of uninitialized variables

```
<?php
// Unset AND unreferenced (no use context) variable; outputs NULL
var_dump($unset_var);

// Boolean usage; outputs 'false' (See ternary operators for more on this syntax)
echo($unset_bool ? "true\n" : "false\n");
```

- Notice `outputs NULL` even on an undefined variable.

---

> *"@mistermartin I guess I would have expected the notice occur when declaring $a; rather than when trying to access it at var_dump($a);? – MonkeyZeus"*

That's because you didn't try to access it in any way, shape or form.

Simply doing: (being a valid statement I might add)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$a; // Awaits further instructions. Won't complain till then.
```

Won't throw a notice up until you introduce `var_dump();` or any other valid function that may use it.

- Think of it as gas on the ground being right at your feet. It won't do much really, up until you introduce a lit match (or Zippo).

Another being "echo" without the `var_dump()` would throw a notice but without NULL.

I.e.:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo $a; // This will make it complain, as will var_dump($a); in its place.
```

Throwing:

> Notice: Undefined variable: a in /path/to/file.php on line x